# Injecting jquery changes page results totally - in a bad way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx, phantomjs

I am new to phantomJs, and was tasked with automatically scraping some data off a site.  to do so I had to sign in, navigate to the search page on the site, search and scrape the results coming from an Ajax query. it all went sweet on my local machine (ubuntu OS with Lampp) but when I moved my code to our dev server (a centOS machine running nginx) I started getting :"refrenceError: $ not defined"  on my calls to jquery. so I've added jquery to my directory and tried:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
   page.injectJs('jquery-1.10.2.min.js'), function(){
       $.noConflict();
   };
   loadInProgress = false;
};
```

and also

```
page.injectJs('jquery-1.10.2.min.js'), function(){
    $.noConflict();

    //DO SOMETHING WITH $ HERE
};
```

but now the search result, which initially was a nice looking page with a table I could navigate in, turned to a `<pre></pre>` element, with only one page of results and no buttons whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is injected into the page context, not the phantom context. It you use `page.injectJs()`, jQuery can only be accessed through `page.evaluate()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to reply. I am aware of that. I had no problem with accessing jQuery from the .evaluate scope. The problem was the adverse effect jquery was having on my search result